# Сортировка элементов в компонентах WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Можно ли через XAML разметку задать сортировку в коллекции, которую я собираюсь биндить или коллекция должна быть заранее отсортирована?

Comment: На сколько я знаю - да, должна быть отсортирована в коде.

Comment: Либо сортировать исходную коллекцию (если сортировка часть бизнес-логики), либо воспользоваться `ICollectionView` (если сортировка чисто для целей представления). В любом случае, без написания кода не обойтись.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/819741/218063