# Фильтрация ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть `ListBox` и `TextBox`, первый подвязан под `ObservableCollection<Adress>`, где Adress -

```
public struct Adress
{
    public Adress(string text, double x, double y)
    {
        Text = text;
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public string Text  { get; set; }//Именно это свойство отображается в "ListboxItem"
    public double X     { get; set; }
    public double Y     { get; set; }
}
```

`TextBox` подвязан к свойству-строке, в сеттере которой я пробовал проводить фильтрацию, но всё тщетно. Фильтровать пробовал с помощью `ICollectionView`, но не разобрался как именно достичь желаемого результата.

А теперь о том, что же собой представляет желаемый результат - при вводе текста в `TextBox`, те элементы в `ListBox`'е, которые содержат этот текст(вне зависимости от регистра) - остаются видимыми, а остальные "прячутся"(думаю просто использовать `Visibility.Collapsed`, но тут уж все средства будут хороши). Вот не могу понять, как это реализовать не нарушая принципов MVVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В итоге разобрался сам, всему виной была моя собственная невнимательность - я не правильно указал `Binding` для `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding AdressFilterText}"/>
```

Таким образом следующий код является полностью рабочим:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding AdressFilterText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Adresses}"/>
```

И C#:

```
private readonly ICollectionView _adressFilter;

ctor()
{
    _adressFilter = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Adresses);
    _adressFilter.Filter = Filter;
}

public ObservableCollection<Adress> Adresses { get; set; }

private string _adressFilterText = string.Empty;
public string AdressFilterText
{
    get => _adressFilterText;
    set
    {
        if (value != _adressFilterText)
        {
            _adressFilterText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AdressFilterText));
            _adressFilter.Refresh();
        }
    }
}

private bool Filter(object @object)
    => ((Adress)@object).Text.Contains(_adressFilterText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: на мой взгляд, `ICollectionView` должно находится в `View` если следовать классике `MVVM`

Comment: @FoggyFinder, а как `ViewModel` о нём узнает, если тот будет во `View`? Или я как-то не так понял?

Comment: никак, если фильтрация используется только для представления, то `VM` не нужно знать о том, что сейчас отображается пользователю

Comment: @FoggyFinder, хм, пожалуй вы правы. А фильтровать тогда с помощью `Behavior`?

Comment: фильтровать можно через и `ICollectionView` на уровне View, если правильно вас понял. `MVVM` не означает отказ от `code-behind`